# How To accept File and object in springboot controller java

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, multipartform-data

[enter image description here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/g3pNpqSMcFATNNcaA)

I want to accept Both file and object that will send on swagger to Spring boot controller **I will Receive request in my controller like **

```
 @PostMapping("/document/upload")
public void uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestBody FileUpload jsondata){...}
```

It will not work for me ----------415   Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryoOpC1bcOXKJ7ETXw;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use @RequestPart instead of @RequestBody.
For reference -
https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/07/27/requestbody-and-multipart-on-spring-boot/